Prove that if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that the image of any open set is open, then $f$ is injective.
I learn mathematics by myself and have no tutor or professor to check on my work, so I wish to check if my resolution to this problem is adequate. 
Here is my attempt at it: 
Suppose $f$ is not injective - that is, that there are $x,y \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) = f(y)$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f|[x,y]$ attains its maximum, say $M_{[x,y]}$, and its minimum, say $m_{[x,y]}$, in that interval (Weierstrass' theorem). We may always take $x$ and $y$ such that $f(x) = f(y) = M_{[x,y]}$, in case $f$ is decreasing at $x$, or $f(x) = f(y) = m_{[x,y]}$, in case $f$ is increasing at $x$: take $y$ to be the closest point to x s.t. $f(x) = f(y)$. In this case, for $A = (x,y), f(A)$ will be of the form $(b, M_{[x,y]}]$ or $[m_{[x,y]}, a)$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, contradicting the supposition that $f$ maps open sets onto open sets. 
Is it correct? If so, is it formal enough, or too convoluted?

What is your definition of decreasing and increasing at a point?

I say it is increasing at x if there is a neighborhood V = (x - a, x + a) s.t. for y, z in V, y > z implies f(y) > f(z), and similarly for decreasing at x.

By this definition, a point can be simultaneously non-increasing and non-decreasing. For example: the cosine function at 0.

That is true. So I should replace the assertions regarding increasing/decreasing at a point and simply say "if f(x) < M_[x,y]" or "if f(x) > m_[x,y]", right?

Your notations are inconsistent. You already used the symbol $x$, and you defined $f(x) = M_{[x,y]}$.

So I should say: "We may always take x and y such that $f(x)=f(y)=M_{[x,y]}$ or $f(x)=f(y)=m_{[x,y]}$: indeed, if $x,y'$ are such that $m_{[x,y']} < f(x) = f(y') < M_{[x,y']}$, then from the intermediate value theorem, there will be some $c \in (x,y)$ s.t. $f(x)=f(c)$. If $f(x)=f(c)=m_{[x,c]}$ or $M_{[x,c]}$, then we are done; if not, we repeat the process. We must stop at some point, otherwise we would have found an infinite sequence $a_n$ with $\lim a_n = x$ and $\lim M_{[x,a_n]} > f(x)$ (or $m_{[x,a_n]} < f(x)$, contradicting the fact $f$ is continuous at x."

I've come to realize this is wrong too, sorry

This approach will not work, I realized $f(x) = x^2\sin (\frac{1}{x}), x \ne 0; f(0) = 0$ is a counterexample

Note that an open set in the reals cannot have a maximum or a minimum pretty much by definition; so if $f(x)=f(y)$ for $x<y$ the open (by hypothesis) set $f(x,y)$ has a maximum or minimum as noted in the OP and that is a contradiction

Thank you, it is much more concise!

You give a definition of "increasing at a point" and "decreasing at a point" and analyzed  the problem in those two cases. What about the other cases? What if the function is neither increasing nor decreasing at any point?

Suppose $f$ is not injective on $\mathbb R$, then there are $x_1<x_2$ such that
$f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.
Consider the function $$f:[x_1,x_2]\to f([x_1,x_2]),$$
then $f$ is not constant function on $[x_1,x_2]$, otherwise $f((x_1,x_2))=\{f(x_1)\}$ is closed set. So there exists $x_3\in(x_1,x_2)$ such that $f(x_3)\neq f(x_1)$. W.L.G, we suppose $f(x_3)>f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then $f$ has maximum on the closed interval $[x_1,x_2]$ at some point $x_0\in(x_1,x_2)$,
i.e.,
$$f(x_0)=\max_{x\in[x_1,x_2]}f(x)=\max_{x\in(x_1,x_2)}f(x).$$
but the range $f((x_1,x_2))$ is not open, because $f(x_0)$ is not an interior point of $f((x_1,x_2))$.
